# Convert 4 digit number to time in excel

Tags: excel

I have been facing problem while I convert 4 digit number to time by using this formula

```
{=INT(C2/100)/24+MOD(C2,100)/1440}
```

and

```
{=ROUNDDOWN(C2,-2)/2400+MOD(C2,100)/1440}
```

when I have more than 60 and below than 100 value.

```
900 = 9:00 
100 = 1:00 
75 = 1:15
```

please if you know the exact formula to convert Number to time pls. suggest me.

---

Comment: Look [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/75618/converting-a-decimal-number-to-hh-mm-ss-format-in-excel)

Comment: I have posted an answer that returns what you show as your desired outcome.  But why do you want an entry of `75` to show a greater time than an entry of `100`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(A1<100,TIME(0,A1,0),TIMEVALUE(REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1)-1,0,":")))
```

Then you will need to format the cell as `[h]:mm`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try with this formula too,

`=IF(A1<100,TEXT(TIME(0,A1,0),"h:mm"),TEXT(A1,"#0\:00"))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
=--TEXT(A1,"00\:00")
```

and format the cell as `h:mm`  or `[h]:mm`

[image]